# Qual a diferença entre aplicativo nativo e PWA

Tags: aplicação-web, pwa

Preciso desenvolver um aplicativo para um site que já existe.
Parte do conteúdo desse site, estará no aplicativo.

Estava pensando em desenvolver um aplicativo utilizando [GoodBarbers](https://pt.goodbarber.com), um serviço onde é possível desenvolver um aplicativo, sem utilizar programação. E eles geram o código em Objective-C (para iOS) e Java (para Android).

Existem outros serviços parecidos no mercado, que disponibilizam o aplicativo de forma híbrida. Como se ele emulasse o webview dos navegadores. 
Será que seria mais vantajoso fazer assim? Talvez eu perdessem em performance se comparado a um aplicativo nativo.

Mas, ao pesquisar sobre isso, me deparei com PWA, que de certa forma faz algo parecido. Mas, fiquei um pouco confuso com o seu funcionamento. No caso, seria tipo um aplicativo também?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento gostaria de saber se de fato isso pode se comportar como um aplicativo. Ou se o funcionamento é somente pelos navegadores mobiles.

Comment: PWA é um recurso de alguns navegadores que cria um atalho especial no celular que quando ativado, abre o navegador, geralmente sem a moldura para parecer uma aplicação nativa, e carrega seu app. O app pode ter partes cacheadas localmente, e um JS fazendo controle de rota, para determinar quais recursos serão carregados ou gerados localmente, e quais remotos. Basicamente é isso, um "atalho bem melhorado" para o navegador. Quando bem usado, ele potencializa os recursos já conhecidos de desenvolvimento web, para tentar ficar um pouco menos distante dos aplicativos nativos.

Comment: @Bacco e como esse atalho é disponibilizado? O usuário tem que criar, ou posso fazer como se fosse um aplicativo?

Comment: @FelipeGoulart  Basicamente ao acessar o site onde se encontra o PWA, o navegador oferece a opção de vc criar um atalho. Teste aqui: https://pwa.rocks/

Comment: @Bacco gostaria que fosse algo parecido com o Facebook Lite.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, o facebook lite não é PWA. Seria bom você ver PWAs existentes pra visualizar até onde eles chegam. PWA não faz milagre. Fique atento para isso: PWA é "progressive **WEB** apps". Talvez melhorem um pouco a integração no futuro, mas tende a ser sempre um navegador abrindo um site com partes cacheadas no aparelho, nada mais que isso.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart depende do navegador ter suporte isso ou não Google Chrome do Android suporta e algumas versões do iOS (não sei em que pé anda) o Chrome OS 67 também passou a suportar. Não é necessariamente suportar o PWA, mas sim fornecer o que vc precisa para cria-lo.